# gate pillars have shifted

Tags: gate-post

Our 2 gate pillars are made of blocks of concrete.  They have shifted and now I can't close the gate.  The top 2 blocks on both pillars have a big gap now.  Is there a quick fix for this?  Do the pillars have to torn down completely and build new ones?

Comment: Can you provide a photo?

Comment: Since all we hav is your description it sounds like more than just 2 blocks shifted, possibly the footing , if that is the case it may have to be disassembled a new footing that can take the stress of the gate side loa. To make it really solid some rebar in the blocks and fill with concrete if the base is solid this won’t move.